# Protractor JS Invalidselectorerror

Tags: selenium, protractor

I'm getting `InvalidSelectorError` when i tried to find anchor tag with certain href in li  in some div :

```
txt1 = ptor.findElement(protractor.By.xpath("//div[@class='caption'][1]//ul//li[1]//a[contains(@href='http://www.youtube.com/')]"));

expect(txt1.getText()).toEqual('Why?')`
```

what is wrong with this since if anchor tags statement is not mentioned then it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a `contains` condition but also using `equals` at the same time:

```
//a[contains(@href='http://www.youtube.com/')]
```

You are looking for:

```
//a[contains(@href, 'http://www.youtube.com/')]
```